# Proof of Sobolev imbedding theorem in Adams

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am struggling to understand the proof of the Sobolev embedding theorem given in Sobolev Spaces by Adams. Specifically section 4.25 (2003 edition).

The aim is to prove $W^{m,1}(\Omega) \to L^{q}(\Omega_{k})$ for $1 \le q \le \frac{k}{n-m}$, where $k>n-m$, and $n \gt m$

$\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open and satisfies the cone condition and $\Omega_{k}$ is the intersection of $\Omega$ with a k-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Lemma 4.24 gives $W^{m,1}(\Omega) \to W^{m-1,p}(\Omega)$ for $1\le p \le \frac{n}{n-1}$

Since $k \gt n-m$, we have $k \ge n-m+1 \gt n-(m-1)r$ $\forall r \gt 1$

The proof (with some obvious misprints) now claims (from previous parts of the proof) that 
$W^{m-1,r}(\Omega) \to L^{q}(\Omega_{k})$ $\forall 1 \le q \le r^{*}$
But I can only see that this is true for $r \le q \le r^{*}$.

Hence finally I get 
$W^{m,1}(\Omega) \to L^{q}(\Omega_{k})$ for $1 \lt q \le \frac{k}{n-m}$.

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: This is true if $\Omega_k$ is bounded due to embeddings of $L^p$-spaces.

Comment: Your statement is missing any assumptions on the domain. Please include them: they do matter for embedding.

Comment: Thank you both for replies. I have added the assumptions on the domain (open, satisfying the cone condition). So $\Omega_{k}$ does not have to be bounded.